# Expo uses old code even though new code has been deployed

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react-native app that is using Expo.

In the beginning of the project I pushed some code to the default publishing channel that was never intended to be used in production.

Since then I have released dozens of versions to production and mostly all works as expected. (New installs gets the latest JS code)
However, a few users still gets old versions of the code, even though they literally just downloaded the app from App Store / Google Play.

This is extremely frustrating. How can I make sure that fresh downloads of the app will download the correct/latest version och my JS?

Note that this is not related to the app detecting new code that might be available for download. It is the fact that the wrong code is downloaded and used to begin with. Is there any way to remove all JS-code except the very last version that I published? I imagine that would solve my issue

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you got any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yeah. You need to rebuild the react native bundle before publishing.https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, expo don’t always do this successfully. You need to rebuild the react native bundle before publishing.https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d

Answer (score 0):

This is what expo gives as a feature known as Over the Air updates (OTA). Whenever a new version is built with expo channel, it automatically updates even in the app store and play store. But there is a way to disable the updates. the expo documentation for disabling:

> It is possible to entirely disable OTA JavaScript updates in a standalone app, by setting updates.enabled to false in app.json. This will ignore all code paths that fetch app bundles from Expo's servers. In this case, all updates to your app will need to be routed through the iOS App Store and/or Google Play Store.
>   This setting is ignored in the Expo client.

And I do recommend you to read the documents of OTA, which is a good feature when you get to know all of it.
The expo link is [expo OTA](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-ota-updates/)